# semaphore keys lost after some time

Tags: php, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a parent-child processes using shared memory.
Child put data into shared memory about 10 times per second.
Parent and child are using semaphore to lock resource while writing/reading.
This solution works for several hours and then I start getting warnings:

> PHP Warning:  sem_acquire(): failed to acquire key 0x4101f1fb: Invalid  argument in script.php on line 350
>   
> PHP Warning:  sem_release(): SysV semaphore 140105644163240 (key 0x4101f1fb) is not currently acquired in script.php on line 354

It looks like the script is over some limit and semaphore destroyed, but I can't find anything in *ipcs* referring to the current limits/use.

I also tried to *sem_get* in order to get new semaphore ID but I can't pass it to child via shared memory *shm_put_var* is not working with resources.

What is the best way to handle semaphores in that long run processes?

Comment: Personally I think technologies like [Redis](https://redis.io/) have made the whole OS level semaphore and shared memory allocation obsolete.

Comment: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice

Answer (score 4):

Could be an ever-existing bug in PHP:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44109

The first (and only) comment speaks of ~32000 semaphore identifiers and that the number is not adjustable...